# How do I separate a graphene/graphite oxide and NaOH solution without centrifugation? (filtration didn't work)

Tags: organic-chemistry

The graphene oxide solution was made from electrolytic exfoliation of graphite electrodes in a 10M NaOH solution. Some graphene powder deposited on the bottom of the recipient but a brownish solution remained, even after the powder settled. Graphene oxide is believed to be the source of the brown color.

The solution still has a lot of the hydroxide present so evaporating the solvent also leaves that compound behind along with the brown crystals, so it's hard to identify if it is actually graphene oxide or just impurities.

Right now I don't have a centrifuge, and filtration didn't work, so how do I separate them?

Comment: The literature is full with ways to wash and dry graphene.

Comment: @Karl Yes, I saw some methods using dialysis membranes but I can't afford these at the moment, but thanks for the answer anyway

Comment: Come on, you don`t need new medical grade membranes. Be creative!

Comment: @Karl Well I think I'll probably have to come up with a method for osmosis, since the solution itself is so concentrated. But anyway, thanks for answering

Comment: @Caju do the solution clear after a while with the material settled down at the bottom of the flask? If yes, decantation could work for you.

Comment: @FelipeS.S.Schneider Actually it doesn't, for a long while all it did was to decant the graphite particles, but not the supposed brown ones